# There is a way to get the first row after UNION?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rownum

I´m trying to get the most repeated values in two columns for me this query is running ok and I´m getting the results as expected. But I only want the first row it´s possible to get this with ROWNUM =1? Or something similar?

My environment is Oracle 11 and SQL Developer.

My code:

```
SELECT AIR_ARB, COUNT(*) FROM
(
SELECT AIR_ARB FROM AIR_INFO  WHERE  V_VX IN (910208,910209,9......) AND V_Y IN
(826369,826370,8.....)
UNION ALL
SELECT AIR_MAT FROM AIR_INFO WHERE  V_VX IN (910208,910209,9......) AND V_Y IN 
(826369,826370,8.....)

) t
GROUP BY AIR_ARB
ORDER BY COUNT (*) desc
```

My results:

```
AIR_ARB COUNT(*)
null     64
100      23
0        20
72       15
143       3
43        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT AIR_ARB, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM (SELECT AIR_ARB FROM AIR_INFO  WHERE  V_VX IN (910208,910209,9......) AND V_Y IN (826369,826370,8.....)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT AIR_MAT FROM AIR_INFO WHERE  V_VX IN (910208,910209,9......) AND V_Y IN(826369,826370,8.....)
           ) t
      GROUP BY AIR_ARB
      ORDER BY COUNT (*) desc
     ) a
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also limit results by using a percentage as bellow, add the expression bellow after "ORDER BY"

```
 FETCH FIRST 0.01 PERCENT ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: This will not return 1 row if there are 200+ rows.

Comment: @Sparallo . . . This is not supported in Oracle 11.

Comment: it always limits your result 0.01*100  row, independently from your result size

Comment: @GordonLinoff, apology, I did not see the Oracle Version you are using

Answer (score 1):

If your `IN` lists are identical then you can use `UNPIVOT` then `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and then filter by `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` after ordering.

This means that you only need to write the lists once (making the query easier to debug and maintain) and Oracle only needs to scan the `AIR_INFO` table/index once (whereas `UNION` may use two scans).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT value AS air_arb,
         COUNT(*)
  FROM   AIR_INFO
  UNPIVOT ( value FOR type IN ( AIR_ARB, AIR_MAT ) )
  WHERE  V_VX IN (910208,910209)
  AND    V_Y  IN (826369,826370)
  GROUP BY value
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
)
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

So for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE air_info ( v_vx, v_y, air_arb, air_mat ) AS
SELECT 910208, 826369, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 910209, 826370, 3, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

this outputs:

> ```
> AIR_ARB | COUNT(*)
> ------: | -------:
>       2 |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=da49ba3812efecf2f42581c400503345)*